# Moving the Wordpress Publish Module

Tags: wordpress, post, module, publish

On the Wordpress dashborad page for writing a new/editing an existing post, is it possible to have the 'Publish' module appear at the bottom right (be the last module on the right) as a default, without having to drag and drop it there?

I'm okay with changing the code in the core files, I just need to know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure these configurations are stored in the database. Check the wp_options table on your database.

Once you find it, you should just use a simple SQL script for each new installation of WordPress.

EDIT: [This link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) came in pretty handy as it describes every table on your db:

> wp_options - The [Options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Panels#Settings) set under the
>   Administration > [Settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Panels#Settings) panel are
>   stored in the wp_options table. See
>   [Option Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) for option_name and
>   default values.

I'm not sure if wp_options is the table where this is specifically stored, but you'll probably find it somewhere in your DB.